# Realtime voice call with 2 person using nexmo/vonage

Tags: php, laravel, vonage

is it possible to do realtime voice call using nexmo/vonage with PHP or Javascript via web browser?
i used library called nexmo/laravel.
This sample code that i used:

```
$nexmo = Nexmo::calls()->create([
  'to' => [[
    'type' => 'phone',
    'number' => '855969818674'
  ]],
  'from' => [
    'type' => 'phone',
    'number' => '63282711511'
  ],
  'answer_url' => ['https://gist.githubusercontent.com/jazz7381/d245a8f54ed318ac2cb68152929ec118/raw/6a63a20d7b1b288a84830800ab1813ebb7bac70c/ncco.json'],
  'event_url' => [backpack_url('call/event')]
]);
```

with that code i can send text-to-speech, but how can i do realtime voice conversation person to person?

Answer (score 0):

From the code you shared above, it looks like you might not have instantiated a client instance of the Nexmo PHP SDK, which is necessary to do so. You make an outbound call with an instantiated and authenticated client.

For example, first instantiate a client with the following, supplying the file path to your private key file, your application ID, your API key and your API secret. You can obtain all of those from the [Dashboard](https://dashboard.nexmo.com/sign-in)

```php
$basic  = new \Nexmo\Client\Credentials\Basic('key', 'secret');
$keypair = new \Nexmo\Client\Credentials\Keypair(
    file_get_contents((NEXMO_APPLICATION_PRIVATE_KEY_PATH),
    NEXMO_APPLICATION_ID
);

$client = new \Nexmo\Client(new \Nexmo\Client\Credentials\Container($basic, $keypair));
```

Then, once you have a credentialed client, you can then invoke the `$client->calls()` methods on it. For example:

```php
$client->calls()->create([
    'to' => [[
        'type' => 'phone',
        'number' => '14843331234'
    ]],
    'from' => [
        'type' => 'phone',
        'number' => '14843335555'
    ],
    'answer_url' => ['https://example.com/answer'],
    'event_url' => ['https://example.com/event'],
]);
```

You can find more information on using the PHP SDK on [GitHub](https://github.com/Nexmo/nexmo-php#making-a-call). You can also find code snippets, tutorials, and more instructions on our [developer portal](https://developer.nexmo.com/voice/voice-api/overview).

Comment: I already put the credential like api_key,secret,app_id,private.key on .env file and successfully make call. But there is problem, i can only make call with text-to-speech. How can I do realtime voice convertation?

Comment: From your code you provided above, if you are indeed using a credentialed instance of the SDK, and you can hear the text-to-speech from your NCCO, then you are successfully connecting. At this point, someone from support would need to examine your account specifics to make sure there isn't something else going on. Can you send an email to support@nexmo.com with your API key (not your secret) and they can look into the logs for you?

Comment: On further note, it is very possible that you are connecting your one outbound call to the named conversation you created "weekly-team-meeting" as shown in the NCCO JSON in your `answer_url`, but then you need to either use the `connect` action to put inbound calls into that conversation or transfer more outbound calls to that conversation.

Comment: thanks ben for your response, i'll try to contact them